# Добавление данных об узлах дерева в базу данных

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

При построении простого дерева в браузере, нужно записать данные об узлах дерева в базу данных.

Это код который отрисовывает само дерево:
script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
let root = "<ul class='ul' style='list-style-type: none;'>" +
    "<li><p id='root' class='mb-0 pl-3'>Root</p><button class='delete btn btn-danger'>- 
</button> <button class='add btn btn-success'>+</button>" +
    "</li></ul>";
$("#create-root").click(function () {
    $("#tree").append(root);
    $("#create-root").remove();
});
$('#tree').on('click', '.add', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').append(root);
});
$('#tree').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
});
```

index.html

```
<body class="my-2 mx-3">
<button id="create-root" class="btn btn-success">Create root</button>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

В базу должны попадать данные id родительского узла id дочернего узла и текст узла.

```
id | parent_id | text
1  |     0     | root
2  |     1     | root
3  |     1     | root
4  |     2     | root
```

Застрял на этапе какие данные передавать в файл main.php при добавлении узла, а так же при удалении узла с его дочерними узлами. То есть как обозначить что создан корень дерева и последующие его узлы? и данные об создании узлов записать в базу данных или же данные о удалении узлов удалить из базы данных.

Comment: Вы же написали таблицу с данными, которые нужны. Очевидно, что их и нужно передавать. В чем сложность?

Comment: не могу прийти к мысли, какие данные нужно передать со стороны клиента на сервер, чтобы произошла запись в базе данных. К примеру если я нажимаю на кнопку добавить узел то какие данные должны пойти на сервер?

Comment: Ну, у вас в таблице строка - в ней три поля, их и передавать. `id | parent_id | text` Вы же в момент клика/создания кнопки знаете эти данные, так их и отправляйте.

Comment: Мне не совсем ясен Ваш ответ. У меня есть пустая таблица в базе данных с такими полями `id | parent_id | text` . При нажатии на кнопку с id=create-root у меня должен создастся корень дерева и в таблице должна появится запись `1 | 0 | root`

Comment: Не очень я все-таки понял, в чем затруднение, посмотрите ответ, может, как-то вас натолкнет на мысль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При добавлении узла дерева добавлять информацию о нем и его родителе куда-нибудь в этот элемент. В примере ниже это тег `<p>`, в общем-то не важно.

```
var lastId = 0;     // последний созданный id

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#create-root").click(function () {
        $("#tree").append(addRoot($(this).siblings('p').attr('elem_id')));
    });
    $('#tree').on('click', '.add', function () {
        $(this).closest('li').append(addRoot($(this).siblings('p').attr('elem_id')));
    });
    $('#tree').on('click', '.delete', function () {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
    });
});

// Для добавления элемента создадим функцию, которой передадим id родителя
function addRoot(parent_id) {
    parent_id = parent_id ? parent_id : 0;
    let text = "Root";
    let root = "<ul class='ul' style='list-style-type: none;'>" +
        "<li><p id='root' elem_id='"+(++lastId)+"' parent_id='"+parent_id+"' class='mb-0 pl-3'>"+text+"</p><button class='delete btn btn-danger'>-</button> <button class='add btn btn-success'>+</button > " +
        "</li></ul>";

    // здесь вы можете дописать отправку данных на сервер.
    console.log('id: ' + lastId);
    console.log('parent_id: ' + parent_id);
    console.log('text: ' + text);

    return root;
}
```

Для удаления просто пройтись по всей ветке до конца, собрать ид элементов и сделать запрос к бд на удаление.

Если у Вас в таблице бд поле **id** - автоинкрементное, тогда вместо ручного расчета `lastId`, как в этом примере, вставлять запись, получать ее id и подставлять в элемент.

Comment: @МаксиСтепанов спасибо за ответ, все предельно ясно.